# I want to flag or mark an answer as favourite for future use. Is that feature available yet on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, questions, bookmarks

So I come across an interesting answer on Stack Overflow and I would like to view or use it in the future.

How would I do it besides copying the link into my notepad or write on a piece of paper?

I would request a feature to flag a answer as a favorite or something similar.

Comment: That already exists: https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=favorites

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the little star underneath the question's score i.e. just below the downvote button to mark a question as a favorite.

[image: favorite button]

You can then [find favorite questions via your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6578055/gnyasha?tab=favorites).